# Drag in touch input conflicts with pinch/zoom

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

here are some parts of the code that I used for the drag and zoom of the camera. First I zoom out using two fingers, then release one of the finger. But when I drag the remaining finger, the camera jumps into the last finger position.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        Touch currentTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            hit_position = currentTouch.position;
            camera_position = Camera.main.transform.position;
        }

        if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            current_position = currentTouch.position;
            LeftMouseDrag()
        }

    }

    // if two fingers are touching the screen at the same time ...
    else if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        isDragging = false;
        Touch touch1 = Input.touches[0];
        Touch touch2 = Input.touches[1];

        etc...


void LeftMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(current_position) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit_position);
    direction = direction * -1;
    Vector3 position = camera_position + direction * panSpeed;
    Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x, initialCameraHeight, position.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set a bool to true once a second finger has been placed (pinching has begun). You can then prevent the drag method from happening until pinching has ended, or the number of touches has reset back to 0 (the bool is false).

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
    {
        isPinching = false;
    }
    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && isPinching == false)
    {
        Touch currentTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            hit_position = currentTouch.position;
            camera_position = Camera.main.transform.position;
        }

        if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            current_position = currentTouch.position;
            LeftMouseDrag()
        }

    }

    else if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        isPinching = true;
        isDragging = false;
        Touch touch1 = Input.touches[0];
        Touch touch2 = Input.touches[1];

        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @eldergoose. It works great but is there a way to continue dragging with the last remaining finger without the camera jumping to its new finger position?

Comment: For that scenario you would have to store the position of the camera at the end of the pinch scenario, and then move it relative to the movement of the finger, instead of setting the camera position directly to the location of the finger. so...
1. at the end of a pinch, store distance between camera position and remaining finger position. 
2. move camera based on finger position + the difference, for example... 
camera_pos = new Vector2(touchpos_x + diff_x, touchpos_y + diff_y)